# Writing Fragments for Polymorphic Associations in RelayJS and GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, graphql-js

My backend schema has a model, `Request`, that uses a polymorphic association such that several different models all have-many Requests and a `Request` can belong to any one of those different models.

I've got a React Component, `RequestList`, that I want to be able to use in any of it's potential parent models.

Here's some sample code:

FooShowView.js

```
class FooShowView extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <RequestList router={this.props.router} />
    )
  }
}

export default Relay.createContainer(ShowView, {
  initialVariables: {
    FooId: null
  },
  fragments: {
    viewer: (variables) => {
      return Relay.QL`
        fragment on Viewer {
          Foo(id: $FooId) {
            id${ RequestList.getFragment('Foo') }
          }
        }`
      `
    }
  }
});
```

RequestList.js

```
class RequestList extends Component {

  renderRows = () => {
    return this.props.requests.edges.map(edge => edge.node).map((intReq, i) => {
      return (
        <RequestRow
          request={ intReq }
          key={ i }
        />
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Table>
        { this.renderRows() }
      </Table>
    );
  }
};

export default Relay.createContainer(RequestList, {
  fragments: {
    foo: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Foo {
        requests(first: 10) {
          edges {
            node {
              ${ RequestRow.getFragment('request') }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  }
})
```

The problem is that now to render the RequestTable for another one of `Request`'s parents, say in the `BarShowView`, I'd need to add a new fragment to `RequestList`:

```
bar: () => Relay.QL`
  fragment on Bar {
    requests(first: 10) {
      edges {
        node {
          ${ RequestRow.getFragment('request') }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`,
```

And then Relay will spit out warnings that I need to provide both bar and foo as props to my List, even if it's not relevant to the current view.

Since `Request` is associated with roughly 8 different models in my schema, this will quickly become unreasonable.

What is the correct way to create a reusable react component that will render the polymorphic children of whatever record I'm looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing (in case someone runs into this) is just putting the `RequestList` fragment on the root and just passing in variables so it only queries for the appropriate associated records. Much simpler than having to write a half dozen fragments. So my createContainer call now looks like:

```
export default Relay.createContainer(RequestList, {
  initialVariables: {
    fooId: null,
    barId: null
  }
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Viewer {
        requests(
          first: 10,
          fooId: $fooId,
          barId: $barId
        ) {
          edges {
            node {
              ${ RequestRow.getFragment('request') }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  }
})
```

Note: if you're wondering why I'm passing up both fooID and barId instead of "requestableType" and "requestableID" it's because I'm using Elixir which doesn't support that type of polymorphism.